# Why does watermark split rows in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm having a problem with this Word [document](http://philofaxy.com/inserts/Personal_Day_per_Page/2016Merged_DayPerPagePersonalOnPersonal.docx). I don't know why when I add a watermark in my document, a row in my table is splited. (See pictures below)

> Document before the watermark:

[image]

> Document after the watermark

[image]

I don't know what I can do to prevent this to happen. I really need help!

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in Word 2013. Which version of Word are you using?

Comment: @Techie007 My word is the Word 2010

Comment: If you remove the watermark, does it go back to the way it was?  Is there a header or footer defined in the document?

Comment: @Techie007 For the first question: yes. For the second question: I think no. You can download this document in this link: http://philofaxy.com/inserts/Personal_Day_per_Page/2016Merged_DayPerPagePersonalOnPersonal.docx Thank you!